# Problems sending data from postman to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, postman

When sending data in postman, no record arrives in the asp.net application, although I think the JSON format is correct and the way I take it in the function is what I think is correct.

[image]

This is the format in JSON:

```
[
    {
        "tag": "1",
        "idDriver": 1,
        "idCentroCostos": 1,
        "idCliente": ""
    },
    {
        "tag": "2",
        "idDriver": 2,
        "idCentroCostos": 2,
        "idCliente": ""
    }
]
```

This is the code that receives the data from postman:

```
        public JsonResult UpdateDataDrivers(List<Driver> oData)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var item in oData)
                {
                Console.WriteLine(tag);
                Console.WriteLine(idcliente);
                Console.WriteLine(centrocostos);
                Console.WriteLine(departamento);
                }

                mensajes.Status = "ok";
                mensajes.StatusMensaje = "return data";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                mensajes.Status = "Error";
                mensajes.StatusMensaje = "Error at finish WS UpdateDataDrivers" + e.Message;
            }
            return Json(mensajes);

        }
```

I also add the postman configuration:

[image]

Using the debugger mode and running the program step by step and placing the cursor over the oData variable shows me that no record was received, which is actually what I need. I attached an image of the problem.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is not happening as you expect. The fact the call produces an output show the call is working at a basic level. Have you set a break point in the `UpdateDataDrivers` method and tracked the data as the method executes?

Comment: As far as I can see everytning works according to your code. But your code is weird, so you get a weird result.

Comment: Hi Sarga and Jhon P. I have changed the code to simply display the objects in the oData list one by one, but that is not really the problem because the problem is the connection between postman and .net, although .net recognizes that it is being called It did not recognize the data that I sent in json format.

Answer (score 0):

You never change the variables from their initial values

Use:

```
string tag = string.Empty;
int idcliente = 0;
string centrocostos = string.Empty;
string departamento = string.Empty;

foreach (var item in oData)
{
   tag = oData.tag;
   idcliente = oData.idCliente;
   centrocostos  = oData.idCentroCostos;
   departamento  = oData.idDriver; //Unsure about this one

   Console.WriteLine(tag);
   Console.WriteLine(idcliente);
   Console.WriteLine(centrocostos);
   Console.WriteLine(departamento);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jonp. The problem really is that when sending the image data via Postman, the image data does not reach the UpdateDataDrivers function, so I don't have information to work with, as seen in the image I just attached. What I would really like to know is if I am doing a wrong configuration in postman or asp.net.